# FxCop 1.36 with CruiseControl.NET 1.5

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, fxcop

I need to run FxCop with CruiseControl.NET 1.5 for continuous Integration. I have included the buildscript with the command to execute the FxCop project file.

When I Build the project in CruiseControl.NET, I get the following error.

```
C:\CPLBuildScripts\CheckpointLearning\FullBuild\Web.BuildScript.proj (19,5):
            
            errorMSB3073: The command "C:\Program Files\Microsoft FxCop 1.36\FxCopCmd.exe /p:C:\CheckpointLearningFullBuilld\CPL.FxCop /o:C:\CheckpointLearningFullBuilld_Artifacts\Artifacts\FxCop_AnalysisReport.xml" exited with code 9009
```

(19,5) Refers to the above  command.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing quotes around the fxcopcmd.exe path.

Comment: oh....i had missed the quotes as u said :(. now its working. ty very much 4 d help :).

Answer (score 0):

You should change the command to

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft FxCop 1.36\FxCopCmd.exe" /p:C:\CheckpointLearningFullBuilld\CPL.FxCop /o:C:\CheckpointLearningFullBuilld_Artifacts\Artifacts\FxCop_AnalysisReport.xml
```